Is it possible to change the widget edit interface after an app update?
We have an app with a released widget which users use. Users can select one of the app models to be displayed in the widget. We want to update the widget and use different data models in the Intent to be displayed in the new version. Based on my testing, widgets always remember the UI generated from the Intent version which was current when they were added to the iOS home screen. For example I can have multiple edit widget UIs at the same time if I add multiple widgets from different app versions containing different Intents.
I ideally want to provide all our users the new configuration screen with the new model and a preset value based on the old widget's setting (I can provide a function which maps old models to the new ones). Is this possible anyhow?
